# How can I transfer content of one table to another database table using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two databases in the same server, I want to transfer the content of one table(posts) to another database table(buss_posts) using the laravel framework.

I update my question

This my post table on the first database

```
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('post_name');
            $table->text('post_content');
            $table->timestamp();
        });
```

This my buss_post table on the second database

```
    Schema::create('buss_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('post_name');
            $table->text('post_content');
            $table->timestamp();
        });
```

and this my controller BlogController

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function run()
    {
       // how can I change between two tables at the different database
       // as you know I am connecting with one database           
    }
}
```

Comment: the most simple is using a raw MySQL query `INSERT ... SELECT ... ` in laraval... this also works across databases on the same server..  consider `INSERT INTO database1.table1 ... SELECT .. FROM database2.table1` ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland how can I change between them in run time ?!

Comment: *"how can I change between them in run time"* You don't have to MySQL does it automatic when use use [fully quatifitied](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) tables inclusing database name

Comment: @Omda could you elaborate more on that?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming both tables have been created and are identical.

Two ways:
 1. if both tables are connected to models. Using eloquent:

```
Model1::query()->orderBy('id')->chunk('1000', function($rows) {
 foreach($rows as $row) {
//create() expects array
   Model2::create($row->toArray());
 }
});
```

2. if they're tables without models. Using query builder:

```
\DB::table('table1')->orderBy('id')->chunk('1000', function($rows) {
 foreach($rows as $row) {
//convert object to array
   \DB::table('table2')->insert(json_decode(json_encode($row), true));
 }
});
```

Might take a while to complete depending on the number of rows. But it won't crash the system cos of the chunk. You might want to place in the code in the `run` method of a Seeder class.

Comment: There's something wrong with method 2. First, chunk() function requires that you use orderBy() and second, $row is a collection object, insert() method does not take collection object, instead, it takes array.

Answer (score 0):

I meet someone solved for me 
I should move to the `config/database` then write down these two connection:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql_1',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'your_first_database'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

then in add seconed database :

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql_2',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'your_second_database'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

and then you should create two models, in my case and put in each connection name like so :

```
Class BussPost extends model
{
   protected $connection = "mysql_1";
   protected $table = "buss_post";

}
```

another model in another database:

```
Class Post extends model
{
   protected $connection = "mysql_2";
   protected $table = "posts";

}
```

and then in your controller, you should do :

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function run()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        $buss_posts = BussPost::all();

      return [
         $posts,
         $buss_posts
      ];

    }
}
```

And update your .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql2
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

That is all, I shard because if someone one day needs it, should use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel seed. You can generate the content of the table using a third party application [iseeder]: https://github.com/orangehill/iseed

then you can run php artisan db:seed --class=Buss_PostTableSeeder

Comment: this will export your database to seeder and then run seeder inside your app.
but I want a way to make me run two databases at the same time to implement some stuff,

and someone solves it ... done! thanks